# Redirect to new page with same input results JS/HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm getting stuck on this I hope someone can help me.

I have made a filter that displays the input and filters when you press the filter button.

When I press the filter button I want to get redirected to another web page and display (Input typed and filter results) the results there. How can I do this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  display: block
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>My Phonebook</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput"  placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<button onclick="myfilter(), mydisplay();">Filter</button>

Search results for <span id="demo"></span>

<hr>

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul>
<script>
function myfilter() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";

        }
    }
}

function mydisplay() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Store your Data in a global variable, I dont know exactly `document` or `window` or something else do it, then redirect to new page and read data from that variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store it in `sessionStorage`, which is preserved between pages of the same domain in the same browsing session.

So, on one page you go:

```
window.sessionStorage.setItem('foo', 'bar');
```

And then, on the other page, you can write:

```
var value = window.sessionStorage.getItem('foo');
```

The variable `value` will now contain `"bar"`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what do you mean by saying "...get redirected to another web page...":

If you mean a URL (location) redirection, than you should:

1. Add your input text into URL **query params**
2. Redirect to this updated URL
3. On new page **load complete** (ex. "onload" event), read the query params and put inside the filter input box.
4. **Call to filter method** as if user clicked the [filter] button

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `<form>` with GET method to pass the searched text to server-side. This form should call itself. Once the form is submitted (you have to have an `<input>` element with type=submit) a new page is loaded with GET information. Then you can write any code to filter the table either on server-side or client-side.

Good luck